# Latest Catalyst drivers on a Sony VAIO (Windows 7 64-bit)

Tags: windows-7, sony-vaio, ati-mobility-radeon, amd-catalyst

Is there a way to install the latest Catalyst drivers on my Sony VAIO (VGN-SR21M, Mobility Radeon HD 3450)? The ATI installer refuses to install it. The AMD website states that for Sony VAIO notebooks I have to use OEM drivers, but the drivers on the Sony website are out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the drivers modified [by Mobility Modder](http://www.hardwareheaven.com/modtool.php). [Direct download link](http://www.hardwareheaven.com/hardwareheaven-tools-discussion/196162-ati-mobility-modder-catalyst-10-1-a-5.html#post1365389).